# Apache mod_jk (or HAProxy) with multiple clusters

Tags: liferay, load-balancing, tableau-api, haproxy, mod-jk

We have two separate clusters (one for Liferay portal, another - for Tableau BI). They are independent of each other. Now I want to use load balancer in high-availability manner (2 servers with heartbeat). The question is the following: is it possible to configure apache mod_jk (or haproxy) so that it do load balancing separately for both clusters? Or we should have independent load balancer for each cluster?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same virtualhost for both clusters?

Comment: Right now I don't see any restrictions on it (because we're in architecture phase, there are no existing clusters so far). The single point is that Liferay will be accessed by external (via internet) and internal users (via intranet) as well but Tableau only by internal. So we're allowed to use any configuration. Indeed, I want to understand if we can use single load balancer appliance for both clusters what is the suitable configuration.

Comment: this forum is for fixing your problem if you show us. let us know what you did so far where you stuck? what is your question exactly? come to the point

Comment: Sorry for inproper use of the forum. My problem was in making proper decision. We try to estimate budget of hardware/software and provide our customer with good estimation and options. So, we know that we'll have Liferay and Tableau, both high-available. We know that we'll use some kind of load balancer hardware/software and we should analyze possible approaches and find the optimal. Because we've never work with apache mod_jk nor haproxy we decided to ask professionals on this forum for the possibility of using single load balancer for both clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are possible and It would depend lastly in your own preferences. Thus, I can think just a only advantage in using two load balancers, which is the ability to manage two load balancers separately using status worker.

This way, you could stop one of the workers in just one loadbalancer so one of your applications will not receive requests in one worker node whilst the other application would continue handling incoming requests. I see this approach like more production grade.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now we can make proper decision.